# How to change the value in the Gradle files after the sync? Is it possible to override Gradle methods?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, font-size

There is an `AutoFitEditText` library that automatically adjusts the size of an `EditText` according to the content.
It is synced successfully with `Gradle`, but the minimum font for EditText is too small (12sp) and I want to make this **16sp**.

The file responsible for this has path: **com/autofit/et/lib/AutoFitEditText.java**

And when I try to change the value: **File is read-only**

The code of this file is:

```
package com.autofit.et.lib;
import ...

/**
 * Created by varsovski on 29-Oct-15.
 */
public class AutoFitEditText extends EditText {
    private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;
    private final RectF _availableSpaceRect = new RectF();
    private final SparseIntArray _textCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();
    private final SizeTester _sizeTester;
    private float _maxTextSize;
    private float _spacingMult = 1.0f;
    private float _spacingAdd = 0.0f;
    private Float _minTextSize;
    private int _widthLimit;
    private int _maxLines;
    private boolean _enableSizeCache = true;
    private boolean _initiallized = false;
    private TextPaint paint;

    private interface SizeTester {
        /**
         * AutoFitEditText
         *
         * @param suggestedSize  Size of text to be tested
         * @param availableSpace available space in which text must fit
         * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
         * text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
         * otherwise
         */
        public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
    }

    public AutoFitEditText(final Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitEditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AutoFitEditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs,
                           final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // using the minimal recommended font size
        _minTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,
                12, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        _maxTextSize = getTextSize();
        if (_maxLines == 0)
            // no value was assigned during construction
            _maxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        // prepare size tester:
        _sizeTester = new SizeTester() {
            final RectF textRect = new RectF();
```

**_minTextSize** is what I need. How to override this?
I'm a newbie with Kotlin.

Comment: Also tried **app:autoSizeTextType="none"**

Comment: I would recommend changing your title to something more relevant to attract more relevant answers to the question. Your issue really has nothing to do with Gradle but more to do with a particular feature in a third-party library.

Comment: Is that Kotlin? Looks like Java)  Usualy custow views have setter and getters to their parameters. Something like setMinTextSize(int size). Also it is possible  that this custom view has attribute that can be set in xml layout.

Comment: @AlexRmcf Already tried. This goes after the XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any knowledge of this library specifically but looking at the sample you provided, `_minTextSize` is set to a constant `12sp` and the library creator hasn't exposed it to be changed. So this isn't really a Kotlin or coding problem, but more a design decision my the developer of the library.

So I would recommend either getting in contact with them and asking for it to be updated with a dynamic minimum text size. Otherwise if you're only using this for testing purposes or for a personal project that won't be published then I don't see any issue with you making a copy and editing them yourself. Just to be clear that I would **not recommend** using this for anything specific (not testing etc.) without checking with them or finding out whether it operates as open source.

---

For the sake of completeness, there are ways to work around this with reflection but this shouldn't really be considered as a valid approach unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: **I don't maintain the library no more. It' been 6 years .** Quoted

Comment: Well then I wouldn't imagine it would be a problem editing it making a copy in your project and editing it yourself